# Flagging a question that can be answered by understanding the basic SQL syntax

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, question-quality

I recently stumbled upon this question.

[SQL Group By comparison with Python Group By error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397747/sql-group-by-comparison-with-python-group-by-error)

If I edit the question and remove the python part of it, it boils down to a single `SELECT AVG(field1) FROM table GROUP BY field2` query.

The OP in his question has made use of `HAVING` in his query which is more advanced than a simple SELECT query. (at least when I started with SQL, it was)

So I thought to downvote and flag it to close. In a matter of minutes, answer was provided which provided the exact query to run, accepted answer, and upvote for the question.

I am not hurt that my flag was declined. But in future, should I leave such questions as it is?

Comment: So you realised what the OP was doing wrong, knew the answer and downvoted and flagged the question? In the future, I would answer it.

Comment: you flagged to close it as what exactly?

Comment: It would surprise me that that question couldn't be closed as a dupe, at least.

Comment: @George answer it and and encourage to ask more of such questions?

Comment: @rene Very low quality

Comment: that is not a close reason ...

Comment: And that question isn't an big pile of rubish so VLQ is the wrong flag

Comment: If you believe the question is closable, just flag it. But if you just have a hunch but not a very clear idea about which close reason apply, do not overthink it trying to close it and leave it for someone else. If you believe the question is not useful for future visitors, feel free to use your votes. And if you think you can help the questioner with a comment (e.g. pointing them they are simply using the wrong syntax), I do not think there is a reason not to do it.

Comment: @nightgaunt What's wrong with basic questions?

Comment: @George There's nothing wrong with the basic questions. They only show lack of effort from OP's side. I do not intend to punish them for it. But I don't want such questions on the site either. The subject has all the words that I might search in future and imagine the frustration when you find this question.

Comment: btw: your VLQ flag got probably declined because [none of the reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20332681) choose *unsalvageable*

Comment: @rene My first thought was to edit and remove the python tag and code. But then, I assumed the question would become VLQ after editing and flagged it. It makes sense to just downvote and move on.

Comment: @nightgaunt I'd disagree, looking at what OP wrote, _" Column 'CSVDatabase.dbo.sales_info.Person' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"_ this error most likely lead them to use `HAVING` then when that inevitably failed they asked that question. It looks like they've tried to solve the problem and then posted, even if it's for a basic problem; that seems fine to me.

Comment: [How to find average of a column in SQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+average+of+a+column+in+sql&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi40IzUvajcAhXIHjQIHc52CA8QBQgkKAA&biw=1343&bih=983) This would give me the answer in first 3 results.

Comment: Why not flag it as a dupe of one of these results?

Comment: @yivi These results are not in stackoverflow.

Comment: Some of them are, and are likely to be good duplicate targets. A duplicate flag helps both the asker and the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A question that's simple or trivial can't be closed for that reason, unless it's a very trivial typo that's spelled out explicitly for them by their compiler or interpreter.

Someone not knowing what they're doing is also not a close reason. If you think a question lacks research effort, just downvote (and hope that nobody will give them a compassion upvote) and move on.